# Can I use Django and HTML extensions at the same time in VSCcode?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I recently started learning Django and when I am writing templates, I have to switch between HTML and Django HTML extensions to use the tab for autocompletion.

With the HTML extension, I can autocomplete the tags using the tab but when Django HTML is in use, it does not work anymore and have to write all the tags manually. Switching between the two is also frustrating, and sticking with the HTML extension means writing the Django syntax (eg. loops, if, and so on) manually also.

Is there any extension that provides this? Or is there any way to use both at the same time? If not, even a quick shortcut for switching between the two would help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can install the `django template` extension. that will enable the autocomplete functionalities for the django template language.

Comment: It does autocomplete the Django template language but does not autocomplete any HTML tags, I need an extension or a way to autocomplete both Django template language and HTML at the same time.

Comment: are you not writing with the template language in a html file??

if you're working on a html file then html atuocomplete will work, and as you installed the django template extension, that will come with help when you're writing something with the template tags.

Comment: Yes, I am writing on an HTML file, but the autocompletion does not work, I thought it is because of the Django template extension, when active, does not autocomplete HTML tags

Comment: brother, you will find a `.vscode` folder in your project directory. just add this line in your `settings.json` file: 

`"emmet.includeLanguages": {"django-html": "html"}`

autocomplete for django template and html both will work fine.@ventoreal_